# error 'symbol' undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: c, compilation, undeclared-identifier

My question is: Why the compiler doesn't run my code if the symbol is declared?

---

I'm trying to run this code on Ubuntu Linux with gcc. But when I try to run it, it says "'i' not declared (first use in this function) return i - 1;". I googled several questions about it.

---

I'm starting with programming and C language and this code is not mine, it serves to calculate the greatest power of 2 that does not exceed N.

```
int power (int i) { 
    int p = 1;
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; ++j) p = 2 * p;
    return p;
}
int lg (int N) {
    for (int i = 0; power (i) <= N; ++i) {}
    return i - 1;    
}
int main () {
    power(2);
    printf("%d", lg(2));
}
```

Comment: The scope of `i` is inside the for loop only, see also https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for#Explanation

Comment: Please pick up a decent beginners book or two, and read the chapters and sections about *scope* and *life-time*.

Comment: `int () main {` ....  are you typing things at random?

Comment: Thanks for answer, grateful. I'll research about for loops.

Comment: @GustavoRossatto It's not about loops specifically. It's about scope.  When you do `for (int i = 0; power (i) <= N; ++i) {}`, then `i` has gone out of scope and doesn't exist after `}`.

Comment: thank you for your attention @TedLyngmo, I googled about scope in c language. So this is why I cannot call the lg() function.

Comment: @GustavoRossatto You can call `lg`. That's not a problem. The problem is that you are trying to `return i - 1;` but `i` is not declared in the scope where you are trying to access it. The `i` in the `for` loop does not exist _after_ the `for` loop. If you need `i` value after the loop, you need to declare `i` _before_ the loop. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/c3EfbxaKe)

Comment: Thank you master @TedLyngmo <3. I was thinking about refactoring the function into a structure or more structure, I was looking into doing that now. I understood that actually the 'I' variable only exists within the repeating structure. Thank's for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables declared in a the first expression of a `for` loop are scoped to the statement. They only exist for the span of the statement (including the body of the loop).

Fixed:

```c
int lg( int N ) {
    int i;
    for ( i = 0; power( i ) <= N; ++i ) { }
    return i - 1;    
}
```

---

As an aside, we can greatly reduce the number of multiplications:

```c
int lg( int N ) {
    int i;
    int p = 1;
    for ( i = 0; p <= N; ++i )
       p *= 2;

    return i - 1;    
}
```

Instead of multiplying, we could divide.

```c
int lg( int N ) {
    int i;
    for ( i = 0; N > 0; ++i )
       N /= 2;

    return i - 1;    
}
```

Comment: Thank u your answer. I hadn't learned yet.  :)

Comment: I added to my answer. And if this answers your question, you can check the mark next to it to mark your question answered.